# Intellij multiple filetypes

Tags: intellij-idea, file-type

I'm using IntelliJ with the handlebars plugin.  One of the nice things about this plugin is the code assist.  However, the only way to get this functionality is by assigning html file type to handlebars, so I lose all the features of having .html files associated with HTML default for IJ.  Is there any way to have html files associated to both the handlebars AND HTML?

Comment: In IntelliJ IDEA these cases are normally handled with `Settings` | `Template Data Languages`, however Handlebars/Mustache doesn't register itself as a template language and therefore it's not available as a choice in this dialog. You should contact the plug-in vendor so that the plug-in is updated to support this configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Handlebars is a template language. Currently IntelliJ doesn't support injection of template languages. It should help you. Please vote for http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-106449